# How to call AngularJS Function through js without using id parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

I want to call AngularJS function without using `id` parameter.

Currently I call the AngularJS function like this

JS File:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('service_search')).scope().showbydefaultSearch();
```

HTML Component:

```
<input id="service_search" type="text">
```

AngularJS File:

```
$scope.showbydefaultSearch = function () {
   // code goes here
}
```

But I want to call `$scope.showbydefaultSearch();` without using any `id` parameter. Then how can I call this function?

Comment: can't you have `ng-click="showbydefaultSearch()"` ? When do you want to call it?

Comment: No, I am getting response in js file so after getting response I want to hit that function.Yeah I can done by using <input> with a hidden field

Comment: what type of reposnse are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using any other selector directly instead of using document.getElement.... For example, using a class selector like  -

```
angular.element('.search-some-class')
```

i have used the id selector to call a controller method from outside with **'#id'** but this should also work.

let me know if this helps.